# Google Calendar API on Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, calendar

I have followed the guide on google developers site on using google API in java.
The authorization thing worked and I pressed "accept" in the browser that started when I run the API in netbeans.

I get a little error in the end in Netbeans which says:

> "Nov 24, 2015 3:10:50 PM
>   com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory
>   setPermissionsToOwnerOnly WARNING: unable to change permissions for
>   owner: C:\Users\xxxxx.credentials\calendar-java-quickstart :run
>   Credentials saved to
>   C:\Users\xxxxx.credentials\calendar-java-quickstart No upcoming
>   events found."

But how do I now proceed in terms of how to use this calendar and making it work inside my java application? Right now it does not do anything.

Comment: You need a file separator when constructing the file path.

Comment: hmm care to explain how i do that?